# C# Adding items with unique numbers in ComboBox with Button Click

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

I am trying to create comboBox items with unique number sequencer.

With each click on button comboBox items should be added like this;

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
...
```

If I modify The name of Item 1; Next click has to name new item as Item 1.
I am unable to create this basic sequencer and require your help.

```
private void addNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //textBox1.Enabled = true;
    //textBox1.Focus();
    comboBox1.Items.Add("item", i);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so whats stopping you? whats the problem

Comment: I can't attach automated unique numbers for each item and unable to prevent duplicate results.

Comment: You need to increment the number to something different each time, try i++ maybe (assuming i is an integer), e.g. comboBox1.Items.Add("item " + i++, i);;

Comment: @Kutay I guessed that, but youve shown no code trying to stop that...  all your items are going to be called item as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define counter on the scope of your form, under form constructor, for example. Like this:

```
int counter = 1;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}
```

in your method for adding items add item with counter  value and then increment counter.

```
private void addNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //textBox1.Enabled = true;
    //textBox1.Focus();
    comboBox1.Items.Add("item " + counter.ToString());
    counter++;

}
```

Comment: Thats perfectly working that was what I was looking for thank you for answer but what is second counter for?
comboBox1.Items.Add("item " + counter.ToString(), counter);

Comment: @Kutay It's not needed here. I had something else in mind so I've edited my asnwer